# React application performance issue

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, performance

I have a ReactJS application which is kind of excel based application with a grid, having rows and columns and formulas for each cell (which may or may not depend on other cells).

I observe that as the grid size and formulas are increasing the application is becoming slower and slower. I am not sure what should I check so that I can improve the performance of the application.

I have made some tweaks on the backend services which helped in fetching the data for which is required by formulas, a bit faster. But the as the calculation itself happens in clientside or on ReactJS itself, I am a bit stuck on what should be my next course of action.
What should I look for? Any specific things I should check for.

My application is hosted on AWS EC2 instance, and I have provisioned a higher capacity (C4.large) so memory and processor should not be an issue in this case.

It is not possible to put code, as it is huge and giving just some parts won't help I think.

Comment: Since there are many pitfalls with react, the description of your problem is not suffice to detect problems in your code.

Comment: Have you used the React Profiler to determine the cost of rendering the various components. Have you confirmed that the performance issue is related to rendering vs. network i/o?

Comment: I think this is more of a computation issue rather than the rendering of components. As I am unable to see anyway, I can do some parallel processing to reduce the calculation of formulas.

Comment: @uday8486 Have you found any turnaround?